# How to lag in data frame and replace the figure with 0

Tags: r, dataframe, na, lag

I want to lag each columns in my dataset except for first column and replace the NA value with 0.

I able to lag the whole first row. However, it also lag my first column and the figure still NA.

Here's my coding that I used:

```
library(data.table)
Country <- c("China", "India", "United States", "Indonesia", "Pakistan", "Brazil",    
         "Nigeria", "Bangladesh", "Russia", "Mexico")
Population.2019 <- c(1433783686, 1366417754, 329064917, 270625568, 216565318,    
                 211049527, 200963599, 163046161, 145872256, 127575529)
Population.2018 <- c(1427647786, 1352642280, 327096265, 267670543, 212228286,    
                 209469323, 195874683, 161376708, 145734038, 126190788)
WorldPopulation <- data.frame(Country, Population.2019, Population.2018)
```

The data frame was like this:

```
             Country Population.2019 Population.2018
1          China      1433783686      1427647786
2          India      1366417754      1352642280
3  United States       329064917       327096265
4      Indonesia       270625568       267670543
5       Pakistan       216565318       212228286
6         Brazil       211049527       209469323
7        Nigeria       200963599       195874683
8     Bangladesh       163046161       161376708
9         Russia       145872256       145734038
10        Mexico       127575529       126190788
```

Here's the lag code:

```
myLag <- function(dat, lag) data.frame(unclass(dat[c(rep(NA, lag), 1:(nrow(dat[2:3])-lag)),]))
myLag(WorldPopulation, 1)
```

And the output come out like this:

```
         Country Population.2019 Population.2018
1           <NA>              NA              NA
2          China      1433783686      1427647786
3          India      1366417754      1352642280
4  United States       329064917       327096265
5      Indonesia       270625568       267670543
6       Pakistan       216565318       212228286
7         Brazil       211049527       209469323
8        Nigeria       200963599       195874683
9     Bangladesh       163046161       161376708
10        Russia       145872256       145734038
```

The output that I want is like this:

```
     Country Population.2019 Population.2018
1          China              0               0
2          India      1366417754      1352642280
3  United States       329064917       327096265
4      Indonesia       270625568       267670543
5       Pakistan       216565318       212228286
6         Brazil       211049527       209469323
7        Nigeria       200963599       195874683
8     Bangladesh       163046161       161376708
9         Russia       145872256       145734038
10        Mexico       127575529       126190788
```

Can anyone figure out how to adjust the coding?

I have try few adjustment but still does get the result that I want.

Comment: The data is just an example. My real data is difference. But my outcome is like that, to get other columns values as 0 after lag. Because after this, there's 4 types of lag I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr` you could do

```
dplyr::mutate(WorldPopulation, across(-Country, ~ tidyr::replace_na(lag(.), 0)))
```

returning

```
         Country Population.2019 Population.2018
1          China               0               0
2          India      1433783686      1427647786
3  United States      1366417754      1352642280
4      Indonesia       329064917       327096265
5       Pakistan       270625568       267670543
6         Brazil       216565318       212228286
7        Nigeria       211049527       209469323
8     Bangladesh       200963599       195874683
9         Russia       163046161       161376708
10        Mexico       145872256       145734038
```

(Data used:)

```
WorldPopulation <- structure(list(Country = c("China", "India", "United States", "Indonesia", "Pakistan", "Brazil", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh", "Russia", "Mexico"), Population.2019 = c(1433783686, 1366417754, 329064917, 270625568, 216565318, 211049527, 200963599, 163046161, 145872256, 127575529), Population.2018 = c(1427647786, 1352642280, 327096265, 267670543, 212228286, 209469323, 195874683, 161376708, 145734038, 126190788)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

`lag()` from `dplyr` package with 0 in its `default` parameter should do the trick.

```
library(dplyr)

WorldPopulation %>% 
  mutate(across(-Country, lag, default = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the example and expected output I don't see any lagging that's happening and you seem to change the 1st row to 0. Since you have loaded `data.table` here's a way.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(WorldPopulation)
WorldPopulation[1, names(WorldPopulation)[-1] := 0]

#          Country Population.2019 Population.2018
# 1:         China               0               0
# 2:         India      1366417754      1352642280
# 3: United States       329064917       327096265
# 4:     Indonesia       270625568       267670543
# 5:      Pakistan       216565318       212228286
# 6:        Brazil       211049527       209469323
# 7:       Nigeria       200963599       195874683
# 8:    Bangladesh       163046161       161376708
# 9:        Russia       145872256       145734038
#10:        Mexico       127575529       126190788
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map_df`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# lag each column except for first column and replace the NA value with 0.

WorldPopulation %>% 
    map_dfc(~ 
        if (is.numeric(.x)) {lag(.x) %>% replace_na(replace = 0)}
        else {.x} )

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    Country       Population.2019 Population.2018
#>    <chr>                   <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1 China                       0               0
#>  2 India              1433783686      1427647786
#>  3 United States      1366417754      1352642280
#>  4 Indonesia           329064917       327096265
#>  5 Pakistan            270625568       267670543
#>  6 Brazil              216565318       212228286
#>  7 Nigeria             211049527       209469323
#>  8 Bangladesh          200963599       195874683
#>  9 Russia              163046161       161376708
#> 10 Mexico              145872256       145734038
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

or the wanted output:

```r
library(tidyverse)

WorldPopulation %>% 
    map_df(~ if (is.numeric(.x)) c(0, .x[-1]) else .x)

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    Country       Population.2019 Population.2018
#>    <chr>                   <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1 China                       0               0
#>  2 India              1366417754      1352642280
#>  3 United States       329064917       327096265
#>  4 Indonesia           270625568       267670543
#>  5 Pakistan            216565318       212228286
#>  6 Brazil              211049527       209469323
#>  7 Nigeria             200963599       195874683
#>  8 Bangladesh          163046161       161376708
#>  9 Russia              145872256       145734038
#> 10 Mexico              127575529       126190788
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>